# What is the name of the component in Lazarus, which name in Delphi is "Canvas"?

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I want to create a paint application in Lazarus, but I don't see the appropriate control, which I can use as a canvas in Deplhi. What is its name ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `Canvas` component in Delphi, but if you're looking for a component, which you can use for custom drawing in your application, then you're looking for the [`TPaintBox`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/extctrls/tpaintbox.html) control (the same name of this component is used also in Delphi). In Lazarus you can find it here in the component palette:

[image]

In newer versions of Lazarus IDE you can advance from the component selector to find components by name. If you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, you'll see the following window, where you just type the name of the control you're looking for and it's immediately filtered. Once you select the component (if there's more than one matching the name) and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the component is selected in the palette:

[image]

You will then write the event handler method for the [`OnPaint`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/controls/tgraphiccontrol.onpaint.html) event of your [`TPaintBox`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/extctrls/tpaintbox.html) component and do your drawing on the component's [`Canvas`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/controls/tgraphiccontrol.canvas.html) there:

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.FillRect(PaintBox1.ClientRect);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

a Canvas is in most cases already defined in Forms-Applications. So simply enter "canvas" followed by a dot to see the functions. This works in all Versions of Lazarus and Delphi.

`procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);

begin

  canvas.TextOut(10,10,'Hello World');

end;`